# Simulate Ready to run instances in BizTalk for Demo purposes

Tags: biztalk

I want to simulate the "Ready to run" message state in BizTalk 2016?

I have sent port and receive port, managed to move files from (In location) to (Out location).

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the Host Instance that the Send Port is on, then it will go into the state of Ready to Run.

Comment: Thanks Man! Exactly what needed